# Paste and Match Style in Rich Text Editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

Currently on a number of my sites I've added description boxes for clients put site information in.

The sites use react where the component used for these is a package called [react-draft-wysiwyg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draft-wysiwyg?activeTab=readme).

Whilst a decent text editor, it comes with drawbacks when pasting text into it. Due to the issues it causes, I would like to enforce a "paste and match style" as its called on mac (think it's different on windows).
This will take the text but not additional styling from clipboard.

For example this in word

[text in word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9blto.png)

Becomes the following within the editor, first normal paste and second to match style

[text in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBLin.png)

Where the formatting doesn't match the output html on the webpage

[text in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDpIM.png)

What I want to be able to do is enforce the non-styled version of the text as default when someone tries to paste text into the editor. I can't seem to find a way to do this through settings so it may have to be a conversion function.

*Apologise for the links seems I'm not able to have images without reputation minimum*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.